# How can I use type as STRING for polymorphic relation table ids (...able_id) table in laravel?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I will use the db example below (modified the example in [laravel docs](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships)) to explain.

### Table structure (modified example)

```
posts
    id - integer
    name - string

videos
    id - string // here I have to use "string"
    name - string

tags
    id - integer
    name - string

taggables
    tag_id - string // should normally be "integer"
    taggable_id - string // should normally be "integer"
    taggable_type - string
```

### Model Relationship (modified example)

```
// Post.php
public function tags()
{
    return $this->morphToMany( Tag::class, 'taggable', 'taggables', 'taggable_id', 'tag_id');
}

// Video.php
public function tags()
{
    return $this->morphToMany( Tag::class, 'taggable', 'taggables', 'taggable_id', 'tag_id');
}

// Tag.php
public function posts()
{
    return $this->morphedByMany(Post::class, 'taggable', 'taggables', 'tag_id', 'taggable_id');
}

public function videos()
{
    return $this->morphedByMany(Video::class, 'taggable', 'taggables', 'tag_id', 'taggable_id');
}
```

In my project I need to use the `videos` table id type as string. According to this, being able to store the relation "videos<->tags" the `tabbables` table's `taggable_id` must be a string as well, otherwise I can't store the relation.

As long as **NO** "video<->tag" relation exist it the table everything works fine but as soon as I add even one single "video<->tag" relation the problem starts.

I can use all available methods on the "video<->tags" relation without any problem. `$video->tags()->attach([1,2])` or `$video->tags()->sync()` or `$video->tags()->detach()` are all working.

But the `post<->tag` relation's methods have problems. Altough I can attach relations like `$post->tags()->attach([1,2])` or call like `$post->tags`, I can't use `$post->tags()->sync()` or `$post->tags()->detach()` methods. When I try, I get this error below:

```
Illuminate/Database/QueryException with message 'SQLSTATE[22007]: Invalid datetime format: 
1292 Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: 'here_string_id_of_video' (SQL: delete from 
`taggables` where `taggable_id` = 300 and `taggable_type` = App/Models/Video)'
```

This is a uncommon and tricky situation. I know that this is logical because the query expects the serched record type to be ingeter. But I need a way to overcome this problem. Any recommendations and views would be appreciated.

---

### UPDATE

Those are some solutions that could come to mind.

1. I could use string type for the other tables as well. Which does not sound plausible. This would need a lot of work.
2. I could process the intermediate table manually with a model.

   App\Models\Taggable::where('taggable_id', '300')
   ->where('taggable_type', 'App\Models\Video')->delete()
3. I could (as @GauravGupta suggested) create an extra id field (external_id) that is string type and keep the native integer id intact.

Comment: How can you use `$video->posts()` in laravel many to many polymorphic relation? Are you trying to use `$video->tags()` or `$tag->videos()`?

Comment: one recommendation for DB always uses the table Id as an integer, If you want something string or like that you can make that as external_id just for showing purpose so that your main data is always sanitized.

Comment: @iamab.in I am sorry but I don't undestand you comment very well. I use $video->posts() but could use $video->tags() or $tag->videos() as well. The point is to be able to 
 use a table with the primary id as string and the issue on using it that way.

Comment: You are right @GauravGupta  that seems one possible way to go.

Comment: Can you define the relation between the models? I can't find the relation between `video` and `post` in laravel documentation or in your sample code

Comment: Sure @iamab.in, in the [laravel documents](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many-polymorphic-relations) it is under the header **Many To Many (Polymorphic)** ,**Model Structure** and **Defining The Inverse Of The Relationship**. I will edit/add the relation as well.

Comment: As per [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many-polymorphic-relations) example and your example relations, you could get `$post->tags`, `$video->tags`, `$tag->videos` and `$tag->posts`. **But** you **can't** get **`$video->posts()`** as there is no method called `posts` in your `video.php` model. If you need that, you might need to write additional relation or chain relations.

Comment: I am assuming your `$video` holds `Video.php` object.

Comment: I got it now @iamab.in you were right. Sorry I guess I was too focused to the problem. I have fixed the part you mentioned. Yes $video holds Video.php.

Comment: From the sql error you provided, I think the error is not related to the video table's `id` column's datatype. Is there any additional columns in your `taggables` table? Do you use soft deletesin any of the models[video, post, tag or your intermediate model].

Comment: @iamab.in Yes I have one additional decimal field: `$table->decimal('a', 12, 3)->nullable();`. Actually I was in the middle of changing all the string ids to integers but you've got a point there @iamab.in, will revert and give it a try without that decimal field.

Comment: @iamab.in no luck with that. I left only the required fields and still get the same result. But there is one point cought my eye.  I ran the query manually the one laravel uses, stated in the error (SQL: delete from `taggables` where `taggable_id` = 300 and `taggable_type` = App/Models/Video). And I got the same `error: Query 1 ERROR: Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: 'here_string_id_of_video' `. The problem seems to be `taggable_id` = 300. It treats the taggable_id as number which is not the case, in my situation it is type of string. As soon I change it to  `taggable_id` = "300" it works.

Comment: Even though it will be the hard way, the best way seems to change the ids to integer type.